# Visual Studio - Files Does Not Showing on the Right

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I just accidentally closed the tab showing the files in the project when i doing my blog project. How can i bring? Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihs1c.png)

Comment: u can try once with shift+ctrl+T

Comment: I tried but it just doing searching. @Sourav Dutta

Comment: ok. This much i know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open up solution explorer here in VS 2022
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Either -

> View > Solution Explorer

or

> CTRL + ALT + L

You can also "pin" the solution explorer menu using the icon that looks like a pin on the top right hand corner of the solution explorer menu